# Adding a newline character and display input from a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I have a text are in a form. I used this code

```
 $('textarea').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var s = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(s + "<br />");
        }
    });
```

to allow users to go the next line using the enter button. *I tried using both 
 and \n*
In the form, the user is able to go to a new line. However, when the input is displayed on a page, the new line doesn't show, and any text after the new line does not appear. However, it is still there- if you go to edit the form it stills shows the text typed after you click enter. I added

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

into the css for text boxes in my css file trying to resolve the issue. However, it still did not work. Any suggestions/ input on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to insert the `<br/>` tag as they type. You really don't want to do anything to their text as they type. If you want to maintain their line breaks, you can convert them to `<br/>` tags before you inject them into an element.

```js
$('#text').keyup(function(event) {
  var text = $("#text").val();
  text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
  $("#result").html(text);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#result {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type in here"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I also tried using \n and \r\n, neither worked, so I don't think simply replacing it will do anything. Since posting, in my debugging, i have also tried adding wrod-wrap: break-word; to the css. Also with no success.

Comment: Did you try what I posted?

Comment: yes, it did not work. I think the issue may be with display text with new lines, rather than in storing the text.